# Best way to implement superclass subclass model based design in rails database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose I am designing database for a online-shop, where they sell different kind of items. Every item has their own distinct property, beside few in common like price, manufacturer, etc. So it can be segregated into superclass (common fields) and subclass (distinct fields)

Say I have this following tables:

```
Product manufacturer:decimal 
Pen ink:string 
Shirt size:int
```

Making a `product_id` field in both `Pen` and `Shirt` table will solve my problem, but is there any other good way to do that? AND is it really a good idea here to segregate it into superclass and subclass?

Comment: This is standard case for MTI (multitable inheritance). There is a gem (naturally) which makes it easy: https://github.com/hzamani/active_record-acts_as

Answer (score 3):

The common approach in this situation is to use Single Table Inheritance([STI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Table_Inheritance)). `Product` would be base class:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

and `Pen`/`Shirt` subclasses:

```
class Pen < Product
end

class Shirt < Product
end
```

Usually all the information would being stored in base `Product` table(that is why it's Single Table Inheritance) and differentiated with a help of special `type` column(of course you would have `nil`s in `ink` field for shirts).

If you want to store only common fields in `Product`s table, you can create separate tables for subclasses. Then, I think you will need not only to specify `type`, but also something like `specific_product_id` in order to be able to pull complete information about the product(it would be something in between STI and [Polymorphic Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)). So it would be like this:

```
Product
id  (product_fields)  type  specific_product_id
1   ...               Pen   2
2   ...               Shirt 7

Pen
id (pen_fields)
2  ...

Shirt
id (shirt_fields)
7  ...
```

Decision is up to you.